# Does SQL server update itself?

Tags: sql-server

I have a web application using hibernate and sql server 2008, suddenly one of my forms doesn't show any data (data of one special table). I can not restore the backup of that database because I think the version changed!!!! But I don't know howwwww it changed? and what should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. Even if new version is available, SQL Server does not update itself. It always asks for permission to update itself. If you don't provide that permission, SQL Server won't be updated.

You may have somehow given your system the permission to update SQL Server.